# Display an SVG output tag as an image for Resizing?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, responsive-design

`<svg id="contradictions-chart" style="width:1200px; height: 500px;"></svg>` currently displays a chart with many code generated objects. I need to make the chart responsive/scalable for mobile. My first thought was to try rendering it as an image. I've tried with no success: `<img src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg id="contradictions-chart" style="width:1200px; height: 500px;"></svg>' />`  It just displays as a broken image.   id="contradictions-chart" pulls the SVG data from a /scripts/main.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION was to use viewBox:

```
<svg id="contradictions-chart" viewBox="0 0 1200 500" style="width:100%">
```

(Syntax: viewBox = "min-x min-y width height")

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the aspect ratio of the SVG is going to be 5:12, then you can can leverage the [padding-top aspect ratio trick](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/) to display it responsively:

```css
.chart-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 41.66%; // 5 / 12 represented as a %
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.chart-container svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart-container">
    <svg id="contradictions-chart"></svg>
</div>
```

Note that you'll need to remove your inline `style` attribute on the SVG element in order for this to work.

Comment: It appears to still want to render all of the SVG and also not be responsive: 
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13giC2T6eQ5MmTdVJZgvdXk5KiQyQe1oQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do you only want certain paths and groups from the SVG to render?

Comment: The entire SVG. I've added a screen cap below to what it currently renders as. I'm trying to figure out a way to size it down to fit on phone. My first thought was to narrow it horizontally. If that doesn't look right then I can scale it down proportionally: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FKzbotwjEhav3s5AyElQgoQvOuMBY3L1/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Is there a possible way to render the entire SVG as an image?